# I don't understand the syntax to this for loop in python

Tags: python

At the moment I'm learning Python from Python Crash Course. I understand that for a for loop has a general format like so:

```
for [iterating variable] in [sequence]:
        [do something]
```

But as I'm reading the textbook I see this new format in the front of the for loop and I was looking up solutions but I didn't know what this might be called.

```
for key, value in user_0.items():
```

I assumed the for loop is designating itself specifically to the dictionary key and that is why there was the word "key" in front of the for loop? Here's a screenshot for a frame of reference if needed.

[image: Picture reference]

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

If `user_0` is a `dict` then it has a method `items()` that returns an iterable view that iterates over the `(key, value)` tuple.

e.g.

```
In [1]: a = {1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6}

In [2]: list(a.items())
Out[2]: [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

It is a handy way of iterating thru both the key and the value of a dict.